# Puzzling "Warning: "this" used in constructor." thrown by Remix static analysis

Tags: solidity, remix

For the following code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract someContract {
  function someContract(address _someAddress) public {
    uint someNumber = 1;
    if (_someAddress != 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000) {
      someContract dCA = someContract(_someAddress);
      if (dCA.getOne() != someNumber || dCA.getTwo() != 2) {
        revert();
      }
    }
  }

  function getOne() public pure returns (uint) {
      return 1;
  }

  function getTwo() public pure returns (uint) {
      return 2;
  }
}
```

...Remix tells me:

> browser/Untitled1.sol:8:15: Warning: "this" used in constructor.
>             if (dCA.getOne() != someNumber || dCA.getTwo() != 2) {
>                 ^--------^
>
> browser/Untitled1.sol:8:45: Warning: "this" used in constructor.
>             if (dCA.getOne() != someNumber || dCA.getTwo() != 2) {
>                                               ^--------^

...I've looked at [the origin of this warning](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/583), but it seems to me that the static analysis is confusing the instantiation of another, existing contract with the current contract. Shouldn't the EVM be able to instantiate an existing contract without issues in the constructor or am I myself utterly confused?